# Publish working paper before submitting to journal

Tags: publications, online-publication

I'm a PhD-student in economics and so far I have no experience with publishing. Before I submit my first article to a journal, I would like to publish it as a working paper. However, I would like to ask if this is useful.
Is it rather the rule or the exception to publish a working paper in advance?
And can the working paper have a negative impact on the subsequent publication in a journal?
Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: By 'publishing it as a working paper' you mean to post it on some Internet repository?

Comment: Do you have a supervisor?

Comment: @Philosopherofscience Yes, maybe on SSRN

Comment: @user2705196 Yes, I have a supervisor

Comment: I cannot comment much. Never did it. I'm always concerned that the journal is going to say that it's already out there.

Comment: What does your supervisor say?

Comment: My supervisor is difficult to reach. Therefore I wanted to ask here.